# Different View/Layout for Landscape Orientation

Tags: ios, swift

I am building a calculator app and have it working in portrait mode. However, I want the user to have more options/functions when they switch to landscape mode. In other words, the entire layout would have to change as there will be more buttons in landscape mode compared to portrait mode.

I have managed to do this using the `installed` property under the attribute inspector. Here are the problems I am running into:

1. When I run the app in portrait mode and rotate it to landscape, I will show the buttons but they are overlapped. Here is a demo(Just wait for the gif to restart):

[image]

2. When I run the app in landscape mode, it displays all the buttons correctly, but as soon as I rotate it again to portrait and then back to landscape, the same problem as #1 happens. Here is a demo (Just wait for the gif to restart):

[image]

What am I doing wrong? How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I've been doing since iOS9. Complete code, does *not* assume you are using IB (I actually think you should not) and should help you with how auto layout works. BEWARE, this *does* assume some knowledge of auto layout and Swift. This also deals with a *very* simple example of a `UIButton`.

First, declare two arrays of constraints, typically in the view controller:

```
var landscape = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
var portrait = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
var myButton = UIButton()
```

Next, set up your **constant** constraints and set the active:

```
myButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addSubview(myButton)
myButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
myButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
myButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
```

So far, so good. You've created a button, added it to the VC view, declared it's size as 40x200. You've also declared it to be anchored to the parent's `safeAreaLayoutGuide` top anchor.

Now, it's time for the "magic". You wish to move this `UIButton` from the bottom to the right depending on orientation. **(Please note, while certain overrides will work on iPhones, iPads, when full screen, will always have a "Regular" size class - in full screen - no matter the orientation!)**

The first thing you need is to put the remaining constraints into the arrays you declared.

```
portrait.append(myButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 10))
landscape.append(myButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -10))
```

Now you have s single constraint to activate. It can be more, remember we are talking arrays. This is simple, just deactivate and activate as needed:

```
func changeConstraints() {
    if isInPortrait {
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(landscape)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(portrait)
    } else {
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(portrait)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(landscape)
    }
}
```

You can even animate things is you wish! Finally, let's tap into the VC life cycle. I'm *very* sure there are other (and better) ways, but keep in mind what I mentioned earlier - in full screen, an iPad will **always** have a Regular size class. So I prefer to dig just a bit deeper. I tend to use three variables - you probably need less.

```
var initialOrientation = true
var isInPortrait = false
var orientationDidChange = false

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    if initialOrientation {
        initialOrientation = false
        if view.frame.width > view.frame.height {
            isInPortrait = false
        } else {
            isInPortrait = true
        }
        changeConstraints()
    } else {
        if view.orientationHasChanged(&isInPortrait) {
            changeConstraints()
        }
    }
}
```

I also have an extension to `UIView`:

```
extension UIView {
    func orientationHasChanged(_ isInPortrait:inout Bool) -> Bool {
        if self.frame.width > self.frame.height {
            if isInPortrait {
                isInPortrait = false
                return true
            }
        } else {
            if !isInPortrait {
                isInPortrait = true
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

I think this should describe most of my code. Basically, (a) *do not* use `UIDevice` nor (b) use `viewWillTransition(toSize:)` and check a size class when working with a iPad. (They *will* have a size class change - albeit differently on devices depending on size, but *only* when in split screen mode. At least for now!)

Pretty much, use (a) `view willLayoutSubviews` - you can use `view DidLayoutSubviews` but I prefer doing things at the earliest point possible - and then (b) check the actual screen size.

Comment: Okay so I got it to work, however, "Vary For Traits" is no longer available since the recent upgrade to xcode 13. I had to use the "install" property under the attribute inspector. However, I am running into a new problem. I will update my question to reflect my progress.

Comment: I don't use IB, so this may not help you with Vary For Traits. But believe it or not, *yesterday* I heard about it. See if this link is of any help: https://useyourloaf.com/blog/xcode-13-vary-for-traits/